# How do I simulate multiple connected pivot joints in a mechanism?

Tags: animation, rigging, physics, rigid-body-simulation

Hi i am doing a dynamic simulation for a project and i want to simulate movement of multiple connected pivot joints. This will be explained further in the following images:

This is the mechanism in State 1, before link extension:
[image]

The links in orange is State 2, which i want the links to be in when i move the left and right platform outwards:
[image]

How do I specify these pin joint constraints to achieve this mechanism?

Thanks!

Comment: is it ok if you make it move with only one of the two platforms? https://zupimages.net/up/22/09/25bv.gif

Comment: @moonboots: but in your gif you moved 2...or not!?

Comment: @ Chris, I make the left move with the right one, I can't do the opposite with this solution

Comment: @moonboots yes, that works! As long as i have a means of controlling the mechanism :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With this solution you can activate the whole movement with the right platform:

[image]

Create this armature, bone_r and bone_l are parented to axis_r and axis_l, axis_l is parented to axis_r, the other bones are not parented:

[image]

Here are the constraints that have been assigned to the different bones: A *Limit Rotation* to pole_r so that it moves along one axis only:

[image]

An *Ik* is given to bone_r with pole_r as controller:

[image]

An *Ik* is given to bone_l with pole_l as controller:

[image]

And at last a *Copy Location* is given to pole_l with pole_r as *Target*:

[image]